# Issues deserializing with service stack

Tags: c#, json, serialization, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I am having issues getting a list of an object out of redis using servicestack. The error is 'Type definitions should start with a '{' array....'

```
using (var redis = _redisService.GetClient())
{
     redis.Set(key, myListOfThings.SerializeToString());
}
```

Appears to be valid formattable JSON in the cache:

```
[{"id":34,"someid":1012,"stuff":"blah"},{"id":33,"someid":1012,"stuff":"dfsfd"}]
```

But I am getting an error thrown in retrieval:

```
using (var redis = _redisService.GetClient())
{
     return redis.Get<List<MyThing>>(key);
}
```

> "Additional information: Type definitions should start with a '{',
>   expecting serialized type 'MyThing', got string starting with: [my
>   json string from cache]"

I even wrapped it so that the list is a child of a main object, which made the JSON start with a '{' but I still got the same error...

I also tried deserializing to an array, and various methods to deserialize but all within the servicestack library,

Any ideas?

**EDIT for anyone else's info**

GetValue method should go hand in hand with SetValue and not Set because of the way it does encoding. I still don't know why Get with a type does not deserialize.

```
redis.Get<DataResponse>(key);
```

This method seems to do the trick:

```
redis.Get<string>(key).FromJson<DataResponse>()
```

Comment: I haven't used redis at all, however, judging by your message: `expecting serialized type 'MyThing'`, it appears *somewhere* you've told it to expect a `MyThing`. Perhaps changing that definition to `List<MyThing>` will fix it ?

Comment: @Rob The error seems to be suggesting a single object is expected but at no point have I suggested that would be the case. So i wrapped it in a single object and I still get the same error that it expects a serialized type of that object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API usage is unbalanced:

If you're serializing the POCO's yourself and **saving the POCO as a string** you should be **retrieving the value as a string** and deserializing it yourself, e.g:

```
redis.SetValue(key, myListOfThings.ToJson());
var dtos = redis.GetValue(key).FromJson<List<MyThing>>();
```

If you want to instead let the Redis Client serialize it, then you should be using the equivalent typed API's for doing that instead, e.g:

```
redis.Set(key, myListOfThings);
var dtos = redis.Get<List<MyThing>>(key);
```

Comment: Yeah I added a later comment realizing my mistake of combining the two - but my issue still stands that redis.Get<List<MyThing>>(key) will not work for me. I have to 'get' with a type of string and deserialize manually. (However GetValue with SetValue does work)

Comment: @Grace Are you trying to `Get<T>` something you saved with `Set<T>`? Because that [does work as expected](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/7cef98a6e4bcd5efd159394f7d0e6c74385d663b/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/Generic/RedisClientTests.cs#L130).